# Can only use 1 water source at a time? Shower stops running when faucet is on, vice versa

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure

Ever since someone came to repair our sprinkler system, our water sources have been completely jank.
If I'm using the water faucet to wash my hands and someone flushes the toilet, the water to the faucet temporarily stops working. 
If I'm taking a shower and someone uses the water faucet or flushes, the shower stops running water. 
If we use two or more water sources simultaneously, only drops or a light drizzle of water will run for both parties.
Why is this? Is it able to be fixed on our own?

Comment: What kind of sprinkler system are we talking about here?

Comment: Sounds more like a flow issue, but its pretty hard to be an internet plumber in this case, we know so little about how the plumbing is designed.   If this problem just started because a sprinkler company serviced your system you should call and tell them they created a problem that you didn't have before and ask them what could have possible happened.

Comment: I wish I could call the company and tell them. But its not even a company. We took pity on someone who was going around our neighborhood asking for work to do. We found out later that this person is undocumented and illegal. So, I won't be trusting them to work further on this since all they did was create more issues. Very stupid on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you still have a leak. A big one. Try cutting off your sprinkler system water supply and see if that helps.

Comment: I'm with you, this sounds like a big leak. I had a sprinkler leak in college (landlord didn't winterize sprinklers) that dumped 126,000 gallons over  a couple weeks before it was caught, no noticeable dip in water pressure. Depending on where OP lives, the water bill could get very large.

Answer (score 0):

The sprinkler guy most likely had to shut off the water supply somewhere, to facilitate repair.

The first thing you should do is find any/all shut-off valves and ensure they are completely open. While checking them, go ahead and cycle the valve(s) open and closed a few times while observing water flow from an open faucet, this is to ensure the valves still work properly. Gate valves (and other types) are susceptible to failure (what we call a "dropped wedge") where the valve gate/disc/wedge partially or sometimes fully blocks flow, even when opened.

You could also be experiencing an obstruction caused by debris that was jostled loose during the work that was performed. This could cause partial blockage of valves, manifolds, pressure regulator(s), fixtures, etc.

[image]